# Кто придумал слово «матлошить»?

Tags: лексика, неологизмы

Ну почему именно  ***матлошить***? Кто и как придумывает такие слова. Почему они не остаются авторскими неологизмами, а используются затем в речи другими пользователями.

**Примеры:**

(1) ***Харрасить*** (от англ. harass приставать, беспокоить, тревожить) — это держать противника в постоянном напряжении и ***матлошить*** **его, как кота**, без отдыху и сроку.

(2) Синицы вообще птицы занятные и не предсказуемые. Как-то осенью моя соседка повесила сушиться платьице своей дочки. Оно было с помпончиками, которые весьма заинтересовали пернатую террористку. Синичка, забыв про всё на свете, уселась на платье и давай ***матлошить*** **эти балабоны**, которые были вдвое больше её. А когда она поняла, что их не оторвать, стала выдёргивать из них нитки и бросать на землю.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141521/discussion-on-question-by-sharon----).

Answer (score 2):

**В украинском журнале "Терем" (1966-й год; Число 2. Березень 1966) встречается слово "матлошить" (в тексте выделено жирным):**

Емма Андіевська

МАРАТОНСЬКИЙ БІГ

Я не знаю, чому так склалося моє життя, що
мене позбавили сну. Тобто, звичайно, я лягаю в
ліжко, як і кожна людина, заплющую очі і повер­таюся набік, щоб заснути, але що відбувається да­
лі — у мене просто язик не повертається комусь
у цьому зізнатися. Бо як же ж я когось переконаю,
коли навіть господиня, яка будить мене кожного
дня до праці, завжди твердить, що мене треба тру­сити малощо не півгодини, заки я очуняю. Вона
переконана, що такого сплюха, як я, їй ще не
траплялося мати на помешканні, не знаючи, що я
вже навіть забув, коли заплющував очі. Бо як тіль­
ки я лягаю в ліжко і чую, що ладен заснути, мене
посилають на великі дистанції в маратонський біг
виконувати доручення, від яких часто залежить
доля усього людства, доручення, завжди невід­
кладні, і ледве встигаю на ранок повернутися на
той час, коли господиня будить мене, дорікаючи
поганою звичкою спати підібгавши під себе ноги,
що виглядає, ніби я зриваюся зі старту, замість
того, щоб спати на спині, як усі порядні люди, що
і ліпше для здоров'я і не **матлошить** так ліжка, яке
вона кожного разу мусить наново перестелювати.
Вона дивується, що я завжди виглядаю стомле­
ним, і запевняє, що це від того, що я занадто ба­
гато сплю, не припускаючи, що я скоро просто
забуду, як виглядає сон, бо навіть коли я на праці
і маю вільну хвилину, щоб покуняти над актами
зі статистичними даними, і надолужити втрачене,
я силоміць стримуюсь, знаючи, що мене негайно ж
пошлють бігти з якимось важливим дорученням,
хоч, правда, на коротші віддалі, ніж уночі, і тому
мій маратонський біг, коли я ляжу в ліжко, буде
ще тяжчим, ніж звичайно, бо я мушу кожного ра­
зу долати бурхливі ріки, пустелі й гори на неймо­
вірних віддалях між палацами, куди мені дово­
диться носити вісті. Часто в мене стріляють, пере­
слідують, але мої швидкі ноги завжди виносять
мене неушкоджевим, і саме ця бездоганна витри­
валість прирікає мене щоночі на маратонський
біг, бо всі інші бігуни, яких висилають, не добива­
ються до місця призначення, і тому кожного разу
женуть мене.
Я вже так знаю усю земну поверхню, що можу
бігти з заплющеними очима, бо ноги мої самі роз­
пізнають на дотик кожну місцевість, куди мене
шлють, і хоч мені часто доводиться марнувати ба­гато часу біля переправ, біля яких завжди жахли­
вий рух, бо інколи цілі народи чекають на пере­
праву, я ще ніразу не спізнився з дорученням,
оскільки з роками я в маратонському бігу лише
вдосконалююся. Він набуває такого розмаху, що
коли мені випадково в дорозі на працю десь у віт­
рині доводиться бачити на телевізійних екранах,
виставлених на показ, змагання найславетніших
бігунів світу, вони здаються мені зборищем калік,
які не вміють ступити кроку, не те що бігати.
Але досконалість, що мала б тішити кожного
бігуна, мене ні трохи не радує. Якби мені дозволи­
ли бодай раз виспатися, я віддав би усі почесті
мого бігунства. Тільки на це немає жодної надії, і
я не хочу дурити себе. Так, як стоять справи, я вже
передчуваю, що мені навіть не дозволять спокій­
но умерти, щоб відпочити назавжди. Звичайно,
мені цього так просто в очі не кажуть, тільки ж з
майже непомітних ознак, з тих невловних відтін­
ків ушанувань, якими наділяють мене, цінуючи мої
послуги, я бачу, що на мене вже чатують, щоб тієї
миті, як я назавжди заплющу очі, послати мене
в той скажений маратонський біг, який триватиме
довіку.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А это перевод с украинского: "... когда хозяйка будит меня, упрекая дурной привычкой спать поджав под себя ноги, что выглядит, будто я срываюсь со старта, вместо того, чтобы спать на спине, как все порядочные люди, что и лучше для здоровья, и не МАТЛОШИТЬ так кровать, которую она каждый раз должна заново перестилать."  Итак, матлошить можно еще и кровать, перемешивая простыни с одеялами и подушками. Ну что ж,  жизнь уж такая, покой нам только снится))

Comment: :) Я ввела текст в гугл-переводчик! И всё предложение, включающее слово, ввела, и его часть (часть предложения). Переводы получились такие: "хлопает", "трясёт"!  Если же в гугл-переводчик ввести только слово "матлошить", то перевод - "хлопает". Только нужно выбрать украинский язык языком, с которого осуществляется перевод. https://translate.google.com/

Comment: Він його матлошить! - Он его тревожит! https://translate.google.com/

Comment: Ти багато матлошиш мовою! - Ты много болтаешь языком! https://translate.google.com/

Answer (score 1):

Пофантазирую, опираясь на нижесказанное! Два пирата, их диалог:

- Жан!
- Что, Люк?
- Устал я, давно не отдыхал!
- Иии?
- Сейчас буду матлошить твои балабоны!
- Как та синичка?
- Увидишь! Как кота буду! Без отдыху и сроку!
- Ааааааа! Спасите! Помогите!

...............................

Мателота́ж (от фр. matelot — «моряк»)[1] — похожий на брак социальный институт, существовавший среди пиратов XVII и XVIII веков[2][3].

Это был формальный и постоянный союз между двумя взрослыми мужчинами. Они объединяли свои средства, сражались вместе и заботились друг о друге в случае болезни. Иногда мателотаж выражался в контракте, в котором закреплялось, что в случае смерти одного из партнёров другой наследовал всё его имущество[4]. Иногда при заключении такого союза пираты могли обмениваться кольцами. Практика мателотажа была распространена на островах, населённых пиратами и буканьерами, таких как Тортуга и Эспаньола, поскольку женское европейское население этих территорий в то время было очень малочисленным[5], а отношения с аборигенами были враждебными. Хотя гомосексуальная связь случалась в среде пиратов и буканьеров[6], мателотаж не обязывал к ней, но и не запрещал ее, в первую очередь такой союз двух мужчин подразумевал взаимопомощь и выручку в трудную минуту. Были случаи, когда один из таких пиратов также был женат на женщине; в этой ситуации жена могла иметь сексуальные отношения также и с его мателотом. Некоторые правила или кодексы пиратов строго запрещали поднимать женщин на борт судов, и наказанием за это нарушение была смерть[7]. Некоторые известные пираты и авантюристы состояли в мателотаже, в частности, Александр Эксквемелин, пираты Бартоломью Робертс и Джон Уолден, Роберт Каллифорд и Джон Суонн[8].

Такая практика была столь сильно распространена, что французское правительство со временем оказалось не на шутку обеспокоено тем, что их приватиры переходят к мателотажному образу жизни, и в 1645 году французский губернатор Тортуги потребовал отправить сотни проституток в Новый Свет, чтобы переключить внимание морских авантюристов на отношения с женщинами[9]. В пользу того, что мателотаж был серьёзным, а не символическим союзом, свидетельствует также то, что, когда люди французского флибустьера Франсуа Олоне захватили испанскую колонию Маракайбо (нынешняя территория Венесуэлы) в 1666 году, капитан лично убедился, что все мателоты погибших пиратов получили свою долю трофеев.

Обычай пиратов и буканьеров использовать прозвища вместо реальных имён, особенно по прибытии в Карибский бассейн, имел целью остаться анонимными перед европейским обществом, скрыть свою пиратскую деятельность и практику мателотажа. Например, на острове Эспаньола только те мужчины, которые работали на плантациях и были женаты на женщинах, использовали свои настоящие имена[10]. ​

Comment: То есть это слово придумал Люк? Или я чего-то недопонимаю?

Comment: Как бы да! Образно! А поматлошил и блошил = поматросил и бросил!